# Google Analytics can't verify credentials

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-analytics

Google Analytics shows the error:

> Security Problem. Please try reloading the page.
>
> We cannot verify your account credentials. Please verify your account information, then sign in again.

[image]

I am getting the above error when I try to log into my Google Analytics account. I have no idea how to get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks, my email is everywhere on the web, not a problem for me. What kind of tags would you suggest?

Comment: Have you visited your account information page and logged out and back in? Does it happen regardless of your browser / OS?

Comment: Have you tried reloading the page as it suggests?  Have you tried clearing your cookies and/or browser cache?   Have you tried another browser, or (if available) logging in from another computer?